# How to give border to Multiple cell and Column at once?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

While exporting data into Excel I have a data with merge cell like:- `https://www.screencast.com/t/XKglDLIi4ND6`.

How can I put the border all around multilple cell Like `https://www.screencast.com/t/lkrIeKhF8Vg`?

For bordering in one cell in cell format My border class is :-

```
Borders borders = new Borders(
                    new Border(), // index 0 default
                    new Border( // index 1 black border
                        new LeftBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                        new RightBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                        new TopBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                        new BottomBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                        new DiagonalBorder())
                );
```